# QGIS: How to cluster near polygons so that each cluster has similar total area of polygons inside?

Tags: qgis

I need to group polygons that are near each other, so that each group of polygons has similar total area. I'd like to set a number of clusters needed and QGIS or some plugin to make calculations and set different group numbers in the attribute table.

[image: examples of polygon clusters]

Answer (score 0):

You are facing an optimization problem just as much as clustering. Some additional details would be welcome as well as, there are numerous ways to think about your problem. Is "area" uniformity in individual polygon areas or the total area of each cluster? Are you defining the "area" as a target in the clustering solution (eg., each cluster area total ~1000ha)? Are you simply after homogeneity in total area of the solution? What type of neighbor contingency are you dealing with (contiguous polygons or space between polygons) and are you wanting to consider weights that include higher order neighbors?

I am not aware of an extension in QGIS that help here but, the [GeoDa C++ library](https://geodacenter.github.io/) has functions that can optimize a clustering solution around a defined target. You can access the GeoDa library using API's in Python ([pygeoda](https://github.com/GeoDaCenter/pygeoda)) or R ([rgeoda](https://geodacenter.github.io/rgeoda/)). There is a GUI software and it looks like the clustering models are now available (as of the latest release) so, this will simplify you analysis considerably.

The Max-P model can be used to solve for a target value using, greedy, Tabu Search or, Simulated Annealing. If your goal is to just end up with arbitrary homogeneous regions I would imagine that the Automatic Zoning Procedure (AZP) would suit your needs. For an algorithm that requires defines *k* (number of clusters), you may need to write a script that iterates through several values of *k* to find the solution that you are after.

Your neighbor contingency is an important consideration as well. For point data distance is a suitable spatial constraint. However, polygons vary by size so, something like centroid distance becomes difficult to incorporate into a clustering algorithm in a meaningful way. As such, one builds a spatial weights matrix *Wij* to represent the spatial relationships between the polygons. The way this is done will vary based on the type of neighbor relations your data exhibits. If the polygons are not touching then you can define *Wij* a edge-distance to the *Nth* nearest neighbor, otherwise it can be a straight Queens contingency. There are a few functions in GeoDa to derive *Wij* but, it is up to you to correctly specify the neighbor relationships.

Comment: It's a Land subdivision optimization issue. My finale purpose Is green maintainance of a municipality in which there are severail green areas. I'd likes tò optimize the Total number of lots to assign maintainance within. Each lot should have more or less a similari Total area and the green areas within should be near each other. My target single Total area for each lot should be TOTAL AREA/N LOTS. but i Need tò male some simulatoons tò choose the best number N of lots.